# Different result from same PromQL

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, prometheus, istio, promql

Recently I am trying to learn Prometheus, and I would like to customize an metric name to refer to a complex native PromQL.

Part of Config File:

- record: `workload_qps_in_unit_time` <- The new one I defined
- expr: `round(sum(irate(A_BASE_METRIC[5m]))by(xxx,xxx,xxx), 0.001)` <- The original I want to replace

How I Use:
My Metric: `workload_qps_in_unit_time{xxx,xxx,xxx}`
The Original PromQL: `round(sum(irate(A_BASE_METRIC{xxx,xxx,xxx}[5m], 0.001)`
Those parameters ("xxx" shows above) are same.

The question is that why the result is different when I call the metric I defined and the original one in the meantime? (in my case, the result value will be 2 times bigger than the original one)

I tried to write this in config file, but nothing different.
`round(sum(irate(A_BASE_METRIC{xxx=~".*",xxx=~".*",xxx=~".*"}[5m]))by(xxx,xxx,xxx), 0.001)`

Comment: Recording rules are evaluated only once every `evaluation_interval`, by default `1m`. Change step of the graph to 1m and you'll get similar results for both queries

Comment: One more thing: naming of metric in use doesn't suggest that it's a counter. Unless this is your own metric, that doesn't comply with naming conventions, it is a gauge and `irate` shouldn't be used on it.

Comment: I'd recommend using rate instead of irate, because irate doesn't catch spikes - it returns results based on a subset of raw samples. See https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832

Comment: `irate` vs `rate` in recording rules with `evaluation_interval` most likely bigger then `scrape_interval`*2 definitely adds to confusion in this situation.